# Uses of destructor = delete;

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

Consider the following class:

```
struct S { ~S() = delete; };
```

Shortly and for the purpose of the question: I cannot create instances of `S` like `S s{};` for I could not destroy them.
As mentioned in the comments, I can still create an instance by doing `S *s = new S;`, but I cannot delete it as well.
Therefore, the only use I can see for a deleted destructor is something like this:

```
struct S {
    ~S() = delete;
    static void f() { }
};

int main() {
    S::f();
}
```

That is, define a class that exposes only a bunch of static functions and forbid any attempt to create an instance of that class.

What are the other uses (if any) of a deleted destructor?

Comment: you can of course create an instance of `S` in this case, just use `new S`

Comment: If you wanted to prevent users from creating instances of the class you could `delete` the constructor.

Comment: @appleapple Touché, but you cannot delete it, so it's another way of defining a leak. Anyway, editing to reduce the context.

Comment: @skypjack You can create (and delete) using placement-new even if the destructor is deleted. Maybe this could have some uses in place where you want a global object to manage different subobject and you do not want these subobject to live outside the container...

Comment: *That is, define a class that exposes only a bunch of static functions and forbid any attempt to create an instance of that class.* aka a namespace?

Comment: @Borgleader The fact that I can do it in another way how can help here? I'm not asking for alternative approaches, I already know them, I'm just curious to know what are the uses of `destructor = delete;`.

Comment: You can create an instance by `new` (not local, it's forbidden here), but it occurs into an object being destroyed only at the end of the program. Maybe for singletons?

Comment: @Bentoy13 unlike static object, it is not destroyed (at least no destructor is called), system resources (maybe) will not be returned.

Comment: @Borgleader objects with static methods can be templated on, namespaces cannot.

Comment: Note this also leaks the deleted destructor properties to all subclasses.

Comment: Also, `std::experimental::nonesuch`. Tag type used solely in TMP that you should never have an object of.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have an object which should never, ever be `delete`d or stored on the stack (automatic storage), or stored as part of another object, `=delete` will prevent all of these.

```
struct Handle {
  ~Handle()=delete;
};

struct Data {
  std::array<char,1024> buffer;
};

struct Bundle: Handle {
  Data data;
};

using bundle_storage = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(Bundle), alignof(Bundle)>;

std::size_t bundle_count = 0;
std::array< bundle_storage, 1000 > global_bundles;

Handle* get_bundle() {
  return new ((void*)global_bundles[bundle_count++]) Bundle();
}
void return_bundle( Handle* h ) {
  Assert( h == (void*)global_bundles[bundle_count-1] );
  --bundle_count;
}
char get_char( Handle const* h, std::size_t i ) {
  return static_cast<Bundle*>(h).data[i];
}
void set_char( Handle const* h, std::size_t i, char c ) {
  static_cast<Bundle*>(h).data[i] = c;
}
```

Here we have opaque `Handle`s which may not be declared on the stack nor dynamically allocated.  We have a system to get them from a known array.

I believe nothing above is undefined behavior; failing to destroy a `Bundle` is acceptable, as is creating a new one in its place.

And the interface doesn't have to expose how `Bundle` works.  Just an opaque `Handle`.

Now this technique can be useful if other parts of the code need to know that all Handles are in that specific buffer, or their lifetime is tracked in specific ways.  Possibly this could also be handled with private constructors and friend factory functions.

Comment: I think to make automatic (and, I think, static) storage duration impossible without enforcing a factory (as would be the case with a non-public ctor)  is the salient thing here.

Comment: `~Handle=delete();` should be `~Handle()=delete;` surely?

Comment: @immibis what, `=delete` does not commute with `()`?

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer In 99.99/100 cases you want to delete every object you create.  In the remaining, you do want objects whose lifetime ends when the program does.  It is not a common use case, but the OP asked for any use case at all.

Answer (score 16):

one scenario could be the prevention of wrong deallocation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct S {
    ~S() = delete;
};


int main() {

    S* obj= (S*) malloc(sizeof(S));

    // correct
    free(obj);

    // error
    delete obj;

    return 0;

}
```

this is very rudimentary, but applies to any special allocation/deallocation-process (e.g. a factory)

a more 'c++'-style example

```
struct data {
    //...
};

struct data_protected {
    ~data_protected() = delete;
    data d;
};

struct data_factory {


    ~data_factory() {
        for (data* d : data_container) {
            // this is safe, because no one can call 'delete' on d
            delete d;
        }
    }

    data_protected* createData() {
        data* d = new data();
        data_container.push_back(d);
        return (data_protected*)d;
    }



    std::vector<data*> data_container;
};
```

Comment: Calling this approach "correct" is a bit weird. You'd generally try to avoid `malloc` and `free` in C++.

Comment: I guess the intent here is, using some customized way of allocating and deallocating (factory) instead of `new` and `delete`. Would probably be clearer with names like `my_alloc` and `my_dealloc`; the names `malloc` and `free` are just a very bad example. Also, `my_alloc` should return a proper pointer (not `void*`).

Comment: I still really don't see this as proper C++

Comment: `malloc` could possibly appear in a mixed environment... Ive added a better example

Comment: I've up voted with caveat that a better C++11 implementation would use `std::unique_ptr<>` to achieve the factory destructor but doing so would obscure the mechanics being demonstrated. So it's good example but not the right implementation.

Comment: malloc and free are well defined for C++; this is the common way to implement new(). "You'd generally try to avoid malloc and free " in application level code, but it's perfectly useful on lower levels.

Comment: Neither example is valid C++. If you were to use the pointer returned by createData() to access the object, that would be instantly UB because you can't just access a data object through a data_protected type. It violates strict aliasing rules. Same thing with casting malloc's return pointer. Malloc does not create objects (it might in C++20, were "implicit creation of objects" is introduced) on the abstract machine, so accessing that non-existant S would be UB. That being said, it'll probably work anyway.

Answer (score 12):

**Why mark a destructor as `delete`?**

To prevent the destructor from being invoked, of course ;)

**What are the use cases?**

I can see *at least* 3 different uses:

1. The class should never be instantiated; in this case I would also expect a deleted default constructor.
2. An instance of this class should be leaked; for example, a logging singleton instance
3. An instance of this class can only be created and disposed off by a specific mechanism; this could notably occur when using FFI

To illustrate the latter point, imagine a C interface:

```
struct Handle { /**/ };

Handle* xyz_create();
void xyz_dispose(Handle*);
```

In C++, you would want to wrap it in a `unique_ptr` to automate the release, but what if you accidentally write: `unique_ptr<Handle>`? It's a run-time disaster!

So instead, you can tweak the class definition:

```
struct Handle { /**/ ~Handle() = delete; };
```

and then the compiler will choke on `unique_ptr<Handle>` forcing you to correctly use `unique_ptr<Handle, xyz_dispose>` instead.

Comment: Is that really a disaster to write `unique_ptr<Handle>`? As long as the `unique_ptr` is constructed with the valid deleter `xyz_dispose` in `xyz_create`, once returned `unique_ptr<Handle, xyz_dispose>` will be move constructed into `unique_ptr<Handle>` with the deleter constructed from `xyz_dispose`, isn't it?

Comment: @wasthishelpful: No; unlike `shared_ptr` which type-erase the destructor of the type, `unique_ptr` has no indirection. Also, note that `xyz_create` being a C function it returns a bare bone `Handle*`, not a `unique_ptr`. Finally I would expect a compiler error if one attempts to convert from `unique_ptr<Handle, xyz_dispose>` to `unique_ptr<Handle>`.

Comment: If you're tweaking the definition (presumably in a `#ifdef`), why aren't you writing `~Handle() {xyz_dispose(this);}` instead of deleting the destructor? Now, `unique_ptr<Handle>` does the sensible thing automatically, instead of making you write the disposer into every use of the type (which can be `typedef`ed around, but still...)

Comment: @LThode: I would personally write a class around `std::unique_ptr<Handle, xyz_dispose>`, it would make usage easier (than repeatedly call `.get()` to get access to the raw pointer) and provide encapsulation (the client of the class would be isolated from changes to the C interface). It's a personal choice :) Anyway, I am not saying those examples are great; I am saying they are possible. I've only ever used this in case (1) personally.

Comment: How a C interface can return a class with deleted destructor ? And using different definition for that class depending of language seems unsafe and no portable.

Comment: @Jarod42: A C interface can easily return a class (if the function is written in C++ and simply exposes a C interface). As for the unsafe/lack of portability, theory (the Standard) may agree with you but in practice there's no problem (as long as you don't use `virtual` of course).

Answer (score 7):

There are two plausible use cases. First (as some comments note) it could be acceptable to dynamically allocate objects, fail to `delete` them and allow the operating system to clean up at the end of the program.

Alternatively (and even more bizarre) you could allocate a buffer and create an object in it and then delete the buffer to recover the place but never prompt an attempt to call the destructor.

```
#include <iostream>

struct S { 
    const char* mx;

    const char* getx(){return mx;}

    S(const char* px) : mx(px) {}
    ~S() = delete; 
};

int main() {
    char *buffer=new char[sizeof(S)];
    S *s=new(buffer) S("not deleting this...");//Constructs an object of type S in the buffer.
    //Code that uses s...
    std::cout<<s->getx()<<std::endl;

    delete[] buffer;//release memory without requiring destructor call...
    return 0;
}
```

None of these seems like a good idea except in specialist circumstances. If the automatically created destructor would do nothing (because the destructor of all members is trivial) then the compiler will create a no-effect destructor.

If the automatically created destructor would do something non-trivial you very likely compromise the validity of your program by failing to execute its semantics.

Letting a program leave `main()` and allowing the environment to 'clean-up' is a valid technique but best avoided unless constraints make it strictly necessary. At best it's a great way to mask genuine memory leaks!

I suspect the feature is present for completeness with the ability to `delete` other automatically generated members.

I would love to see a real practical use of this capability.

There is the notion of a static class (with no constructors) and so logically requiring no destructor. But such classes are more appropriately implemented as a `namespace` have no (good) place in modern C++ unless templated.

Comment: Instantiating (and consequently destroying) objects into preallocated buffer is very useful in special environments - e.g., in embedded devices or where performance is critical and the overhead of memory allocation/deallocation is too high (and causes fragmentation)

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername It is useful and there's even a Boost library to implement an allocation pool. It works well when you need to fix overheads or know you'll create/delete many instances. What I'm saying isn't such a good idea is to not call the destructor. If it's trivial then no harm is done. If it's non-trivial you may have avoided a problem. The one that can be valid is just letting execution end and allowing the operating environment clean-up. I'll modify my comments.

Comment: _I would love to see a real practical use of this capability_. That's more or less why I created the question. Set aside the downvotes with no explanation, I still have the desire to know. :-)

Comment: @skypjack It does seem to be there for completeness in those rare cases you decide the consequences of not calling it are benign. It's not as if `=delete` tells the compiler the destructor is trivial. It forbids constructs that result in it being called.

Comment: Classes with static methods can be templated on, namespaces cannot. Not to mention traits classes; are you saying that allocator_traits is bad modern c++? I think your last paragraph overstates its case.

Comment: @NirFriedman The traits example is a good point. I would still think you wanted a namespace with a collection of function templates rather than a static class except you can't pass namespaces in as template arguments which I think is the main point you're making about the "traits pattern".

Comment: "The traits example is a good point. I would still think you wanted a namespace with a collection of function templates" I think in most cases of traits that contain static functions, if you tried to replace the trait with a namespace of function templates, it would work very poorly in practice. Because, class templates can be partially specialized, and function templates cannot be. They can be overloaded, but the rules are different. Also it often leads to worse error messages. I agree with Nir friedman about your last paragraph, these two things may sound analogous but really arent the same.

Answer (score 5):

Creating an instance of an object with `new` and never deleting it is the safest way to implement a C++ Singleton, because it avoids any and all order-of-destruction issues. A typical example of this problem would be a "Logging" Singleton which is being accessed in the destructor of another Singleton class. Alexandrescu once devoted an entire section in his classical *"Modern C++ Design"* book on ways to cope with order-of-destruction issues in Singleton implementations.

A deleted destructor is nice to have so that even the Singleton class itself cannot accidentally delete the instance. It also prevents crazy usage like `delete &SingletonClass::Instance()` (if `Instance()` returns a reference, as it should; there is no reason for it to return a pointer).

At the end of the day, nothing of this is really noteworthy, though. And of course, you shouldn't use Singletons in the first place anyway.

Comment: How can it be the safest way to create a singleton if you can create a second one any time you want?

Comment: @rubenvb: By making the constructor private. Otherwise it's not a Singleton. But that's such a trivial detail that I didn't even mention it.